# Changing the value in a known memory address of a 3rd party process, Java

Tags: java, memory, windows-7, process

Lately I started using Cheat engine to edit the value in the memory of a 3rd party process.
I'd like to know how it can be done with java.
[I am new to this, sorry if I didn't express myself right]

Example : The memory address of a process that I want to change its value is 00514200 (that's what cheat engine shows me)
how do I do this with java instead of cheat engine?

Thanks allot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're aiming to do is a highly platform-dependent task and consequently Java has no built-in methods to do this. Since you say you're new to this, this may not be the simplest thing to start working on, but if you must do it, have a look at the [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) library -- you can use JNA to call Win32 functions that can do this task for you. Specifically, the [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call allows you to modify the contents of another process' memory.